# "von Beruf" but not "Beruf von"?

Tags: word-usage, preposition

I am new to German and I have some questions when asking for someone's job in German:

> Was ist die Person von Beruf?

I was taught that "von" in German means "of" in English like in the sentence

> Was ist der Name von deiner Mama / deinem Papa.

So shouldn't it be

> Was ist der Beruf von der Person?

or

> Was ist der Beruf der Person?

in genitive case.

Also, I can't say

> Ich bin ein Kassierer von Beruf.

but say

> Ich bin Kassierer von Beruf.

or

> Ich bin ein Kassierer.

Comment: All your example sentences are proper German, you might be worrying a bit too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right concerning the generic meaning of `von` being `of. So the following sentences are fully correct:

> Was ist der Beruf von dieser Person?
>
> Was ist der Name von deiner Mama?
>
> Der Beruf von mir ist Kassierer. (Attention: This is bad style. It's better to say: "Mein Beruf ist Kassierer.")

But there is an idiomatic expression in German: `von Beruf sein` meaning the same. It's just like this:

> Was ist diese Person von Beruf?
>
> Ich bin Kassierer von Beruf.
>
> Ich bin von Beruf Kassierer.

So all of your suggested sentences are correct concerning your question.

Comment: Note, I fixed the declination errors as they weren't related to the question.

Comment: "Was ist der Name von deiner Mutter?" is unsual. Use "Waser ist der Name deiner Mutter?" instead.

Comment: Ebenso ist "Was ist der Beruf Deiner Mutter" wesentlich besser als mit dem überflüssigen "von". Das ist aber genau die Frage gewesen.

Comment: @MaxRied and @user unknown: Mir ist schon klar, dass die Genitivkonstruktionen besserer Ausdruck als die generische `von`-Konstruktionen sind. Es geht in der Frage aber nicht um die Genitivkonstruktionen, sondern um die beiden `von`-Konstruktionen.

Comment: Ja, war auch nur ergänzend von mir gemeint. Und mit Autokorrekturquark drin...

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, 'von' is best translated with 'by'. For example, in the passive with non-human agents:

> ich wurde von einer Schlange gebissen.
>
> I got bitten by a snake.

This may also be a case where 'by' is best translation for 'von' for English speakers:

> Ich bin Kassierer von Beruf.
>
> I am a cashier by profession.

Not a native speaker by any means, but that's how I understand the parallels between the German and the English.